# errors with Elif expected indented block

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to create a menu for my application, the menu has 4 options and each of these options should return with the correct information when the user has entered the chosen value. i keep getting an error with the Elif statements.
I am a newbie so please understand where am coming from.
much appreciation.

when i indent the while ans: i will receive an error says invalid syntax after indenting the elif ans==2.

elif ans==2 <--- this error keeps saying indention block error or syntex invalid when i indent it.

def print_menu(self,car):
            print    ("1.Search by platenumber")
            print    ("2.Search by price ")
            print    ("3.Delete 3") 
            print    ("4.Exit 4")

loop=True
    while loop:
        print_menu()
        ans==input("Please choose from the list")

```
    if ans==1:
        print("These are the cars within this platenumber")
    return platenumber_

    while ans:  
        if ans==2:
        elif ans==2:
            print("These are the prices of the cars")
    return price_   

    elif ans==3:
        print("Delete the cars ")
    return delete_ 

    elif  ans==4:
    return Exit_  

            loop=False

    else:
        raw_input("please choose a correct option")
```

Comment: you have `while ans:` and then no indentation after it. If you finish a line with `:` there should be indentation following

Comment: when i indent it afterwards i recieve an error says invalid syntax

Comment: Going from your question, though its hard to understand the logic at work, Your `return` statements are oddly indented and you have a `while` statement thrown into the middle of your `if` statements. Why are you in a `while` loop in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `while` loop without a body. Generally speaking, if there is an indentation error message and the error is not on the line mentioned, it's something closely above it.

```
loop=True    
while loop:
    print_menu()
    ans = int(input("Please choose from the list"))

    if ans==1:
        print("These are the cars within this platenumber")
        # return some valid information about plate numbers

    elif ans==2:
         print("These are the prices of the cars")
         # return some valid information about pricing 

    elif ans==3:
        print("Delete the cars ")
        # Perform car deletion action and return 

    elif  ans==4:
        # I am assuming this is the exit option? in which case
        # return without doing anything

    else:
        # In this case they have not chosen a valid option. Send
        # A message to the user, and do nothing. The while loop will run again.
        print("please choose a correct option")
```

Also, your code is a bit confusing to me. It looks like you're going to `return car_` no matter what, which means your loop will only execute once. Also, `=` is assignment and `==` is equality. Be careful.

Comment: should i remove elif and add if statment after the while ans: what would you recommend ?

Comment: thanks i will keep trying , thanks for your feedback